# how to copy only pdf from folders and subfolders?

Tags: command-line, regex, copy

I have a folder with about 20 subfolders, each with 10-15 subfolders. Is there a way, using CLI to move only PDf files to a new folder?

Comment: use rsync with arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy only pdfs from all sub-directories, type:

```
rsync -rv --include '*/' --include '*.pdf' --exclude '*' /path/to/parent/source/directory/ /path/to/Destination/directory
```

Comment: Glad! it helped.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the difference between the command you posted  and this one:  find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec cp {} ./destination_folder \;

Comment: rsync is a different program that copies, find is program that find files and exec is a program that executes arguments. So, when you use find and exec together it finds the files and executes the arguments given by the user.

Comment: @simplemind - : )

Comment: @Raphael exec is a shell built-in, true, but the `-exec` seen with find is an option of find itself, and not an external command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cp` with bash's `globstar` enabled (see [this U&L question on recursive globs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob)):

```
shopt -s globstar 
cp some/folder/**/*.pdf target/folder
```

Or, `find`:

```
find some/folder -iname '*.pdf' -exec cp -t target/folder {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` with `-exec` flag is appropriate for that. It by default is recursive and descends into subfolders

If I wanted to move all png files from Downloads to Downloads/PNG folder, I would do this:
`find $HOME/Downloads -type f -iname "*.png" -exec mv -t $HOME/Downloads/PNG {} +`

In your case,

`find /path/to/top/folder -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec mv -t /some/other/place {} +`